# Merge [factory] into [factory-pattern]

Tags: feature-request, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

It turns out that [factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory) is about the pattern too:

> an OOP pattern to implement an interface responsible for creating objects.

But [factory-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory-pattern)'s name is more readable and distinguishable, imo.

Please merge [factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory) (1008) into [factory-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory-pattern) (659), or vice versa. And configure a synonym.

Answer (score -1):

You know, "pattern" is a somewhat annoying descriptive word: basically every topic in software, you could add "-pattern" on the end.

You could possibly make a case that all tags "whatever-pattern", should just have the "-pattern" dropped

Comment: I agree. On other hand `factory` is too generic word. Anyway, I'll be happy with merging any of them into another.

Comment: [Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) is a well-defined term which the Gang of Four traced back to the field of architecture. In the strictest sense, it can be properly applied only to their 23 seminal contributions. It is an over-used term nowadays due largely to attempts at riding their coattails, though a small number of additional published works may qualify for the same category.