# What's up with the usage pattern of [factory-pattern]

Tags: discussion, tags

So I was going through the suggested edits queue and encountered [factory-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory-pattern)

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/factory-pattern/info isn't really descriptive and only suggest to use two other tags. It just tells me, don't use this, use that.

> This tag is sometimes used to refer to the Factory Method pattern ([factory-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory-method)) and sometimes used to refer to the Abstract Factory pattern ([abstract-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abstract-factory)). Please use either of those tags instead of this one.

Yet it still gets used in 1000+ questions, so there seems to be a 'need' for such a tag.

When I look at the usage cases there isn't a really distinctive usage case for the tag, although on first glances it seems it's more relevant for C#. I'm not at home in C# so I can't say/assess anything about the relevance of the tag factory-pattern to C#.

Should we make this tag more specific for C#, synonym it, burniate it add more information, or something else?

Answer (score -1):

The [factory-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory-pattern) tag should probably be [merged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253929/merge-factory-into-factory-pattern) with [factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory) because the two have identical meaning.

That meaning is admittedly ambiguous because there are numerous Factory patterns; but it is quite common for questions to come from users who do not *know* there are numerous Factory patterns. Many people know the word "Factory" and come to SO because they are confused by the wildly varying implementations they find.

The Factory patterns I'm aware of are all object oriented but language agnostic. These tags will tend to be associated with the popular OO language tags; but I would not recommend making them more specific. While usage of these tags tends to indicate general ignorance of design patterns, that description fits quite a number of folks who ask about Factories.

One tag seems necessary as the starting point for users who don't know any more than the word Factory; but two tags is redundant.